# How to apply all transformations including scale, rotation etc and make a 3d model defined from world co-ordinates in blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I am working with blender where i have a scaled and rotated 3d model which was transformed to fit another model. Now i want to apply this transformations into it so that each vertex in the model gets defined from the world origin. How do i do this. I could find that when i export the model in ply format and re-imported the transformations are applied and the model gets defined from the world origin. Is their some way to do this without exporting and importing it again.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a code writing service. If
you [edit] your question to describe what you have tried so
far and where you are stuck, then we can try to help with
specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to **apply** the current state into the default one.

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you can open up the apply menu, where you can choose your apply-method. In your case, you can choose *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale*.

**Tip:**
You can 'reset' your transform by pressing following key combinations. (In that way you can test if your apply worked as you expected.)

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to relocate the selected object (sets position to (0,0,0))
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to reorientate the selected object (sets rotation to (0,0,0))
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to rescale the selected object (sets scale to (1,1,1))